# Multiple PHP queries in one file for AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax

I am a complete noob when it comes to AJAX and was just wondering if:

When creating an ajax call:

```
    $.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url:'http://link.to.php/file.php', 
    data: { 'link': variable},
    })
```

Do I have to create multiple PHP files, each only having the singular query which I would like to use, or can I compile them all together within one file? e.g.

```
**File1.php
//containing a singular query**
<?php

include ('connection.php');
    if(isSet($_POST['link'])){

        $curUrl=$_POST['link'];

        $curUrl=mysql_real_escape_string($curUrl);

        $nextSet = "SELECT * FROM shortlink_analytics WHERE shortlink = '$curUrl' ORDER BY hitTime ASC";

        $array = array();

        $query = mysql_query($nextSet);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $array[] = '<tr><td>'.$row['hitTime'].'</td></tr>';

        }

        echo json_encode ($array);

    }
?>
```

or can I have them like the following:

```
File2.php
//containing multiple querys
<?php

include ('connection.php');
    if(isSet($_POST['link'])){

        $curUrl=$_POST['link'];

        $curUrl=mysql_real_escape_string($curUrl);

        $nextSet = "SELECT * FROM shortlink_analytics WHERE shortlink = '$curUrl' ORDER BY hitTime ASC";

        $array = array();

        $query = mysql_query($nextSet);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $array[] = '<tr><td>'.$row['hitTime'].'</td></tr>';

        }

        echo json_encode ($array);

    }

    if(isSet($_POST['link2'])){

        $curUrl2=$_POST['link2'];

        $curUrl=mysql_real_escape_string($curUrl2);

        $nextSet = "SELECT * FROM shortlink_analytics WHERE shortlink = '$curUr2l' ORDER BY hitTime ASC";

        $array2 = array();

        $query = mysql_query($nextSet);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $array[] = '<tr><td>'.$row['hitTime2'].'</td></tr>';

        }

        echo json_encode ($array2);

    }
?>
```

If I can have it like **File2.php** how can I go about targeting the correct query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run as many queries as you would like on your PHP file that is being called from AJAX.

Keep in mind however, if you are returning JSON data, you want to return everything at once. So just accumulate all of your output data, then push everything at once (the code has been cut down):

```
if(isSet($_POST['link'])){
    $array1 = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $array1[] = '<tr><td>'.$row['hitTime'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}

if(isSet($_POST['link2'])){
    $array2 = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $array2[] = '<tr><td>'.$row['hitTime'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}

$return = array();
if(isset($array1)){
    $return['array1'] = $array1;
}
if(isset($array2)){
    $return['array2'] = $array2;
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

This will allow you to serve up your information much cleaner, when returned to javascript as an object:

```
success:function(data){
    console.log(data.array1);
    console.log(data.array2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on the number of queries you intend to have. The larger this file gets the more processing required, and the harder it will be to manage. If you do use a single file, I would consider using switch statements. Switch and If statements have been benchmarked, and Switch statements are more efficient than If's.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are not different from the page calls. So you can have everything in one .php file like you do it in traditional way ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can have it as in `File2.php`. You can achieve it for example like that:

- in ajax call, add parameter: `data: { 'link': variable, 'query': query},`
- in php page, read parameter: `$action = $_POST['query']; switch($action){...}`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, all the AJAX call does is load the file with the POST / GET variables you provide, and then it gets back the output.

So by using if statements you can keep all of your AJAX call handling code in the same file; if you wish.