# how to use key/value pairs in ajax call for jquery data option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Ive been checking out how to add variables to a ajax request which I can use in my server side script. I checked this stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140879/multiple-php-queries-in-one-file-for-ajax-call) and checked the jquery api docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for a ajax request. I am getting error `variable` in my code is not defined.

I have this line in my code

```
return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/users/show', 
      data: {'currentusershow': variable},
    });
```

I was wanting it to do something like this with the results so I can keep all my different script in the one file.

```
if ($.get("currentusershow")) { 
// do something here 
}
else if...
```

i am not sure how to add the `value` to my code?

Also my url does not work going to the show.js.erb where my code is kept.

Comment: `I am getting error variable in my code is not defined` - the snippet shows no evidence that `variable` is defined

Comment: So do I just have to define it for it to work?

Comment: sure, or just pass in a dummy value seeing as the value of `currentusershow` seems to be unimportant to you ... say `true` or `1` or even an empty string `''` ... you don't have to use a variable if there's no reason to

Comment: sorry, id did that actually, and the error dissapeared but I assumed it was still wrong as i was getting the same response from my app but i think it is actually my `url` value, I get a error 404 for some reason but from what ive searched you just add the controller and action like I have done in my ajax request. Cant figure that part out.

Comment: not knowing anything about the server side makes it impossible to help with what you are doing wrong

Comment: yeah, i will figure this out. Keep it as 1 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mamun was kind of right here as I did not explain myself very well in my question but I thought I would post this and clarify my question with what I was trying to do. The ajax call should be

```
return $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/users/show', 
  data: { currentusershow: 'variable'},
});
```

where the key is `currentusershow` and the value `variable` is a string and leave out defining the variable else where in the code. That way the url comes through correctly to the server being `/users/show?currentusershow=variable`. And in my destination file add my ruby code there to use the variables. In my question that code was more a php type code as I did not know what I was doing at the time.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote here, this is the exact right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and assign some value to the `variable` before the request.
Also you need to change the method type from `GET` to `POST`.

```
var variable = 'some data';
/*$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/users/show', 
  data: {currentusershow: variable},
  success: function (response) {
    // Do something with respsone
  },
  error: function () {
     alert("error");
  }
});*/
$.get( "/users/show", {currentusershow: variable} )
 .done(function( response ) {
  //do something with the response here.
 });
```

Comment: yes this seems right. But i will have to fix my route for some reason I am getting a routing error. Will mark correct when everything working.

Comment: I though the $.get identified the request and the ('currentusershow') picked up the code to return, but its just using the jquery get() method. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: See the changes in snippet now.

Comment: yes that seems right, but I am wondering what to put in the file my request goes to. Like `if .... { do this} else if ... {do this}`? thanks.

Comment: Normally contents of the file you are calling should be json.

Comment: yes but I want to distinguish my multiple scripts in the one js file by the variables sent?

Comment: I am really unable to understand your requirements here.

Comment: Sorry, server side, so the file I am getting the scripts from, they do not fire if you have multiple in there if the call doesn't know which one to get?

Comment: Why do you have multiple files for the same http call.

Comment: No, i mean just one js file my ajax call is going to, but in there there is multiple scripts for other ajax calls, but putting everything in one file stops any call from working.